# Landscape only on XCode 6

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, xcode6

Hi so I've been playing around with XCode and can't seem to figure out how to make an application landscape only. Wondering if there is a simple/storyboard solution.

I've tried checking the landscape left and landscape right and unchecking the portrait on the general page under "device orientation".

However this strangely just displays the w Compact h Regular set up on my storyboard horizontally (as opposed to showing the W Any h Compact set up). I mean technically I can work around this, but it seems annoying/inefficient to rotate my head 90 degrees while working on the portrait settings.

If there is only solution in code, I would appreciate it in swift!

EDIT: Hmmm, after some testing it seems as if the phone I'm testing on only shows the rotated version of the portrait settings. It's an iPhone 4 and maybe outdated for handling 2 seperate set ups for portrait and landscape.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just for anyone with this problem in the future, here's the problem:
The storyboard editor by default will display the editor as any by any, as it should. Size classes should ONLY be used when you need to change something specifically for one kind of size class (in other words, things that will be different on different devices. You should still edit everything in the any x any orientation, and regardless of if it's landscape only because size classes will still change from device to device for landscape orientation.

Answer (score 0):

> It's an iPhone 4 and maybe outdated for handling 2 seperate set ups for portrait and landscape

That could be it. Size Classes were invented in iOS 8. So on a system earlier than iOS 8, they are not supported, and your results will be, shall we say, unpredictable.